# css grid creates empty rows and columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid with 2 areas. It works fine with `grid-template-areas: "list details"`. Why does it create a 3x2 grid if I specify only one area: `grid-template-areas: "list"`? And why does it stick the second area in the bottom right track?

https://jsfiddle.net/o5txebkc/

```css
#main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        "list";
}

    #main .list {
        background: yellow;
        grid-area: list;
    }

    #main .details {
        background: green;
        grid-area: details;
    }
```

```html
<main id="main">
  <article class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
    </ul>
  </article>

  <article class="details">
    <h3>Details</h3>
    <p>
      some details
    </p>
  </article>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Screenshot of grid in Developer Tools]

Using Developer Tools to highlight the grid and show the lines, I see that "details" is positioned outside of the explicit grid. (Notice the negative line numbers.) This behavior changes if you remove `grid-area: details;` from the *.details { }* class rule.

Because you defined a grid-area for "details" but did not give it an explicit position on the grid, it is placed into the implicit grid at the closest row and column where it is not touching the named lines.

[The implicit and explicit grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids#the_implicit_and_explicit_grid)

- Explicit grid: Created using grid-template[-*].
- Implicit grid: Extends the defined explicit grid when content is placed outside of that grid, such as into rows by drawing additional grid lines.

[Counting backwards](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Line-based_Placement_with_CSS_Grid#counting_backwards)

> We can also count backwards from the block and inline end of the grid... These lines can be addressed as -1, and you can count back from
> there – so the second last line is -2. It is worth noting that the
> final line is the final line of the explicit grid ... and does not take into
> account any rows or columns added in the implicit grid outside of
> that.

['grid-area' values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area#values)

> If a name is given as a <custom-ident>, only lines with that name are
> counted. If not enough lines with that name exist, all implicit grid
> lines are assumed to have that name for the purpose of finding this
> position.

Comment: You may be onto something here. However, I can clearly see vertical lines 1,2,3,4 and horizontal lines 1,2,3,4 (3 and 4 are collapsed into one).

https://pasteboard.co/KitFbtOeEYwW.png

Comment: But notice the line numbers. "lists" ends at -1 and "details" starts at 0

Comment: I see what you're saying. It's hard to make sense of these grid line numbers. Basically, the moral of the story is if you have an area name, you better use it or get ready for exotic positioning.

Comment: I have edited my answer to add clarity. In my previous comment, I was wrong to say that "details" starts at line 0. The explicit grid starts at line 1 and ends at line -1 (for counting backward.) Anything outside of that is the implicit grid.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```css
#main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

#main .list {
    background: yellow;
}

#main .details {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<main id="main">
  <article class="list">
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
    </ul>
  </article>

  <article class="details">
    <h3>Details</h3>
    <p>
      some details
    </p>
  </article>
</main>
```

Comment: OP asks "*why*", not "*how*". An answer without an explanation is pretty much a bad answer, by the way.

Comment: @InSync I don't agree, but thank you for your comment

Comment: @SteinTheRuler thanks for the answer, but I was indeed looking for the WHY :)
I can do what I need, but would love to understand the css logic if you don't specify all the children in grid-template-areas

Comment: @DenisD you don't define any Details area. Maybe that's why

Comment: @SteinTheRuler yes, because I was expecting it to be hidden if it's undefined in grid-template-areas. Maybe there's something in the docs saying all grid items must be specified...